# Error in fromJSON(commandArgs(1)) : unexpected character '''

Tags: json, r, scala

I am calling a R script from Scala by using scala.sys.process. This script takes a command line argument in JSON format and processes it. I am using `rjson`'s `fromJSON` function to store the JSON in a list.

This works very fine when I execute the R script from the command line:

```
$ ./dfChargerFlink.R '{"Id":"1","value":"ABC"}'
```

But when I call it from scala, I get the following error:

```
Error in fromJSON(commandArgs(1)) : unexpected character '''
Execution halted
```

This is the code I am using:

```
val shellCommand = "./dfChargerFlink.R '"+arg+"'"
return shellCommand !!
```

where arg is the JSON string.
You can notice that I have appended " ' " to both the sides of the JSON string as if I don't, I get this error:

```
Error in fromJSON(commandArgs(1)) : unclosed string
Execution halted
```

How can this be solved? Is it some bug?

Comment: Try to change the R line `fromJSON(commandArgs(1))` in `fromJSON(gsub("^'|'$","",commandArgs(1)))`. You are removing the leading and trailing `'`, if that character is passed.

Comment: @nicola I guess `fromJSON(gsub("^'|'$","",commandArgs(1)))` removes the `'`. But I then I get the error I have mentioned near the end of my question. I want those `'` to be there. It works when I do it from command line.

Comment: Did you try it? The `'` is not removed from the command, but is removed when the argument is processed from R. It is there. Was it just a supposition that you are going to get the error or you actually tried it and got the error?

Comment: @nicola I tried it and got the error before I commented. I got the `unclosed string` error

Comment: Could you write to a file the  `shellCommand` variable to see the actual command you are passing? Maybe there is a problem in `arg`.

Comment: @nicola yes I did that. The full command is `./dfChargerFlink.R '{"Id":"1","value":"ABC"}'`. I even took the command I passed on the terminal and tried executing it from Scala, it also generated the same error. The SAME command works from terminal but not from Scala's `sys.process` package.